# ruby fatal: Not a git repository WEIRD?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, git

i'm trying to run the script from here: https://www.uludum.org/courses/118-how-to-run-your-own-bitcoin-arbitrage-bot/subsections/2164-installation

You can try follow yourself and test results

I have followed it exactly and yet when I go to open the program I get this and I have no idea how to fix it? ANY HELP IS BIG HELP. I have run git init in this folder:c:\Ruby200-x64\devkit I think that is the right folder? How can I know where to run it?

I have tried to run git init as per google the error but it has not helped and still returns the same error. Have installed gem install minitest as well. Running 64bit ruby and devkit.

```
c:\Ruby200-x64\devkit>gem install rbtc_arbitrage_simple
Successfully installed rbtc_arbitrage_simple-2.1.1
Parsing documentation for rbtc_arbitrage_simple-2.1.1
1 gem installed

c:\Ruby200-x64\devkit>rbtc_simple
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92
:in `block in materialize': Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources
(Bundler::GemNotFound)
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/s
pec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/s
pec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/d
efinition.rb:133:in `specs'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/d
efinition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/r
untime.rb:13:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.r
b:127:in `setup'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.r
b:132:in `require'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage_simple-2.1.1
/lib/rbtc_arbitrage.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage_simple-2.1.1
/lib/rbtc_arbitrage.rb:2:in `chdir'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage_simple-2.1.1
/lib/rbtc_arbitrage.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
5:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:5
5:in `require'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage_simple-2.1.1
/bin/rbtc_simple:4:in `<top (required)>'
       from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rbtc_simple:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/rbtc_simple:23:in `<main>'
```